# Update Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates

I am using Lubuntu 14.04 and the program updater asked for the Lubuntu installation cd to install updates. I already inserted the cd but the updater keeps asking me to insert the installation cd.

I even burned the image again, but the message doesn't change.

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Are you updating 14.04 or trying to upgrade to 14.10? This isn't very clear to me as I cannot imagine 14.04 (an LTS version) requesting a development version. I think it far more likely that you have the original installation cd listed in your software sources and that's what it's looking for (original 14.04 disk)

Comment: I am trying to update the programs in 14.04.

Comment: I first installed it as Lubuntu 13 from a Cd. Some time later it updated to 14.04 (through program updater). Now I got this issue.

Comment: Ok, I'm confused again. a version change is an upgrade, not an update.

Comment: That leaves option 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options.

1) Leave things as they are and provide your original 14.04 disk when prompted.

2) Remove the CD from your software sources (recommended)

Comment: If this isn't clear, please edit your question and include the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: I just removed the CD from my software sources and it worked.

Comment: @JoãoPauloRibeiroReis    Excellent! Feel free to upvote answers that help you here as that helps others with the same problem find the best answer.